# Jeditable new value doesn't save to database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pdo, jeditable

I am following a tutorial to make simple web app and I'm usig jeditable for in place editing.

everything works fine, except that the new value doesn't get saved to the database. the mysql log leads me to believe that the "listItemID" doesn't get through because it shows the statement that is executed as follows:

```
UPDATE list_items
SET ListText='Test123'
WHERE ListItemID=''
LIMIT 1
```

I have this in my index.php:

```
    bindAllTabs("#list li span");
```

this is in my js file:

```
function bindAllTabs(editableTarget) {
    // CLICK-TO-EDIT on list items
    $(editableTarget).editable("db-interaction/lists.php", {
        id        : 'listItemID',
        indicator : 'Saving...',
        tooltip   : 'Double-click to edit...',
        event     : 'dblclick',
        submit    : 'Save',
        submitdata: {action : "update"}
    });

}
```

i have this in my lists.php

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once "../inc/constants.inc.php";
include_once "../inc/class.lists.inc.php";

if(!empty($_POST['action'])
&& isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn'])
&& $_SESSION['LoggedIn']==1)
{
    $listObj = new ColoredListsItems();
    switch($_POST['action'])
    {
        case 'add':
            echo $listObj->addListItem();
            break;
        case 'update':
            $listObj->updateListItem();
            break;
        case 'sort':
            $listObj->changeListItemPosition();
            break;
        case 'color':
            echo $listObj->changeListItemColor();
            break;
        case 'done':
            echo $listObj->toggleListItemDone();
            break;
        case 'delete':
            echo $listObj->deleteListItem();
            break;
        default:
            header("Location: /");
            break;
    }
}
else
{
    header("Location: /");
    exit;
}

?>
```

and then this in class.lists.inc.php:

```
public function updateListItem()
{
    $listItemID = $_POST['listItemID'];
    $newValue = strip_tags(urldecode(trim($_POST["value"])), WHITELIST);

    $sql = "UPDATE list_items
            SET ListText=:text
            WHERE ListItemID=:id
            LIMIT 1";
    if($stmt = $this->_db->prepare($sql)) {
        $stmt->bindParam(':text', $newValue, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $listItemID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->closeCursor();

        echo $newValue;
    } else {
        echo "Error saving, sorry about that!";
    }
}
```

I've spent hours trying to figure this out. I hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Almost a year late but...I've been running around for 2 days with this problem, trying to work the same tutorial.

As you discovered, the problem is that jEditable isn't able to process the ID of the current element and so $_POST['ListItemID'] ends up being empty.

In the bindAllTabs function jEditable *will* accept additional parameters in the `submitdata` field:

```
submitdata: { action: "update", ListItemID: this.id }
```

But the problem with this is that the jEditable call isn't bound to an event that will allow us to use `this.id` - and therefore allow us to get the ID of the current item we're clicking. You can hard-code the value and see that it *then* sets $_POST['ListItemID'] (which is purely an academic test)...and there's no way to grab the current ID on the fly and insert it into `submitdata`. I'm no genius but I've tried almost everything.

**SOLUTION**
I found the fix by editing the code of jEditable itself. This line (I see it on line 176 in jEditable.js):

```
submitdata[settings.id] = self.id;
```

...is where the error is happening. It's blanking because `self.id` isn't coming up with anything. Swap out this line with this bit of code:

```
submitdata[settings.id] = $(self).parent().attr('id');
```

Using `submitdata: { action: "update", ListItemID: $(self).parent().attr('id') }` itself *won't* work.

Also you have to update some other bits in the tutorial since jQuery has deprecated some of the things, but you may have already done this. For instance `.live(/**/)` gets updated to `.on( 'click' , null, function(){/**/});` and so on.